How to Configure GitHub App Authentication in Jenkins Pipeline Script for Secure Repository Access
How can I configure my Jenkins pipeline to authenticate with GitHub using a GitHub App at the organization level, enabling it to push changes and manage repository access? Specifically, what steps are needed to set up the GitHub App credentials in Jenkins, and how should I reference these credentials within the pipeline for secure and seamless authentication ? I have configured the GitHub App in Organization and personal account with the below permissions.
Administration: Read-only
Checks: Read & write
Contents: Read-only (to read the Jenkinsfile and the repository content during git fetch).
Metadata: Read-only
Pull requests: Read-only

stage('Generate JWT and Clone Repository') {
                environment {
                    // Hardcoded Credentials and Repository Information
                    APP_ID = "asdfadsfasdf"                  // Replace with your GitHub App ID
                    INSTALLATION_ID = "1234567"       // Replace with your GitHub App Installation ID
                    PEM_CONTENT = '''
                    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
                    
                    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
                    '''                       // Replace with the full contents of your PEM file
                    REPO_URL = "github.com/org_name/repo_name.git" // Replace with your repo URL
                }
                steps {
                    script {
                        // Step 1: Write PEM content to a temporary file with appropriate permissions
                        // def pemFile = 'github_app_private_key.pem'
                        // writeFile file: pemFile, text: PEM_CONTENT
                        // sh "chmod 600 ${pemFile}"

                        // Step 2: Generate JWT using the PEM file and add debugging for each component
                        echo "Generating JWT..."
                        env.JWT = sh(
                            script: """#!/bin/bash
                            # Generate JWT Header
                            HEADER=\$(echo -n '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}' | openssl base64 | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '\\n')
                            
                            # Generate JWT Payload
                            PAYLOAD=\$(echo -n "{\\"iss\\":${APP_ID},\\"iat\\":\$(date +%s),\\"exp\\":\$(( \$(date +%s) + 600 ))}" | openssl base64 | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '\\n')
                            
                            # Generate JWT Signature
                            HEADER_PAYLOAD="\${HEADER}.\${PAYLOAD}"
                            SIGNATURE=\$(echo -n "\${HEADER_PAYLOAD}" | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign ${PEM_CONTENT} | openssl base64 | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '\\n')

                            # Combine to form JWT
                            echo "\${HEADER}.\${PAYLOAD}.\${SIGNATURE}"
                            """,
                            returnStdout: true
                        ).trim()

                        if (!env.JWT) {
                            error("JWT generation failed.")
                        } else {
                            echo "JWT generated successfully and stored as a global environment variable."
                        }

                        // Step 3: Exchange the JWT for an installation access token and store the response as a global environment variable
                        echo "Requesting installation access token..."
                        env.RESPONSE = sh(
                            script: """#!/bin/bash
                            curl -s -X POST \
                            -H "Authorization: Bearer ${env.JWT}" \
                            -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
                            https://api.github.com/app/installations/${INSTALLATION_ID}/access_tokens
                            """,
                            returnStdout: true
                        ).trim()

                        // Debugging: Output the API response
                        echo "GitHub API response: ${env.RESPONSE}"

                        // Parse the token from the RESPONSE
                        def jsonResponse = readJSON(text: env.RESPONSE)
                        def accessToken = jsonResponse.token

                        if (!accessToken) {
                            error("Failed to obtain access token. Response: ${env.RESPONSE}")
                        } else {
                            echo "Access token obtained successfully."
                        }

                        // Step 4: Clone the repository using the access token
                        echo "Cloning repository..."
                        sh "git clone https://x-access-token:${accessToken}@${REPO_URL}"

                        echo "Repository cloned successfully."

                        // Step 5: Clean up PEM file
                        sh "rm -f ${PEM_CONTENT}"
                    }
                }
            }

Error :
GitHub API response: {
20:03:59    "message": "A JSON web token could not be decoded",
20:03:59    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest",
20:03:59    "status": "401"
20:03:59  }

